# Redshift query to combine result if the data are continous within a table

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift, gaps-and-islands

I have a requirement in redshift where I need to combine result if the data are continuous. I have the following table, where user_id, product_id are varchar and login_time, log_out_time are timestamp.

```
user_id    product_id   login_time                log_out_time
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ashok      facebook     1/1/2017 1:00:00 AM       1/1/2017 2:00:00 AM
ashok      facebook     1/1/2017 2:00:00 AM       1/1/2017 3:00:00 AM
ashok      facebook     1/1/2017 3:00:00 AM       1/1/2017 4:00:00 AM
ashok      linked_in    1/1/2017 5:00:00 AM       1/1/2017 6:00:00 AM
ashok      linked_in    1/1/2017 6:00:00 AM       1/1/2017 7:00:00 AM
ashok      facebook     1/1/2017 8:00:00 AM       1/1/2017 9:00:00 AM
ram        facebook     1/1/2017 9:00:00 AM       1/1/2017 10:00:00 AM
ashok      linked_in    1/1/2017 7:00:00 AM       1/1/2017 8:00:00 AM
```

I need to combine the result if the data are continuous for a given user_id for each product. So my output should looks like,

```
user_id    product_id   login_time                log_out_time
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ashok      facebook     1/1/2017 1:00:00 AM       1/1/2017 4:00:00 AM
ashok      facebook     1/1/2017 8:00:00 AM       1/1/2017 9:00:00 AM
ashok      linked_in    1/1/2017 5:00:00 AM       1/1/2017 8:00:00 AM
ram        facebook     1/1/2017 9:00:00 AM       1/1/2017 10:00:00 AM
```

I tried with the following query but it doesn't helped me,

```
SELECT user_id, product_id, MIN(login_time), MAX(log_out_time) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY user_id, product_id
```

Above query fails to give my required output since it doesn't have the logic to check the data are in continuous time. I need to have a query for this without using any custom function, but I am allowed to use any redshift in-built function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to identify where groups start, then cumulative sum to identify the groups, then `group by` to aggregate the results:

```
select user_id, product_id, min(login_time), max(log_out_time)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_lt = login_time then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by user_id, product_id
                  order by login_time
                  rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                 ) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(log_out_time) over (partition by user_id, product_id order by login_time) as prev_lt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by user_id, product_id, grp;
```

Comment: Your query doesn't gives the required output. If I ran the above query it gives the same source table. I just interchanged the 0 and 1, in that case it produces three rows but it is not the required output. For the row ashok &  facebook I got single row as `ashok, facebook, 1/1/2017 1:00:00 AM, 1/1/2017 4:00:00 AM` but the required output is  `ashok, facebook, 1/1/2017 1:00:00 AM, 1/1/2017 4:00:00 AM, \n ashok,facebook,1/1/2017 8:00:00 AM,1/1/2017 9:00:00 AM`. Required output is available in the question, kindly have a look.

Comment: @ashokramcse . . . I had the login/logout times reversed.  The query needs to compare the current login time to the previous logout time (which is what it is now doing).

Comment: Yup your edited answer solves my mystery. BTW, you are really a genius!!!.